# How to set and get the caret position in a contenteditable div (Dart)?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, shadow-dom, dart-html

How do I set and get the caret position in a contenteditable div?

I'm interested in a method that also works when the contenteditable div is inside a webcomponent (with shadow dom).

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work. If you use no shadow dom, you could just use:
`var root = window;`

Note that with the current Dartium build (nov 2015), there is a bug which prevents the `getCaretPosition` to work correctly with shadow dom. It works after compiling to javascript in the latest chrome.

```
int getCaretPosition(Element element) {
  dynamic root = element.shadowRoot ?? window;
  return root.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset;
}

void setCaretPosition(Element element, int position) {
  final range = document.createRange()
    ..setStart(element, position)
    ..setEnd(element, position);

  dynamic root = element.shadowRoot ?? window;
  root.getSelection()
    ..removeAllRanges()
    ..addRange(range);
}
```

Check the demo at [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bb27f9630ad3cf6cf0b0)